# how to display only date in web page

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a table (Person Details) in which a (date of birth) column is present whose datatype is date, when I execute the query display only date, but when I fetch the data of this column in webpage it display both data and time

Comment: Because you told your application to display it like that... Change the formatting in your application. The presentation layer is in full control of the format of the data presented to the end user.

Comment: There are several ways to do that. It would be easier to help if you posted the code you have tried so far.

Comment: [MSDN : Standard date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're fetching the value into C#, you can use the `DateTime.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy")` on the front end.